# XSLT Condition with ancestor and child

Tags: xml, xslt

i have the following XSLT Script in XSLT 1.0, which I call in many parts of the XML transformation, Please note that the client record will appear multiple times :

```
<xsl:template name=" ReturnClientInfo " match="/">
<xsl:param name="CustomerNumber"/>
                       <xsl:for-each select="/XMLCOVER/Task/TaskData/Contract/ContractRoles/ContractRole/Customer/Identifiers/Identifier[@SocialNumber = $CustomerNumber]">
                       <xsl:if test="position()=1">
                                      <!—Print client details once -->                                             
                        </xsl:if>
                      </xsl:for-each>
                 </xsl:template>
```

Now I need to add another condition that will exclude ContractRole that equals ‘001’, I tried the following script, it returns the same result as the script above.

```
<xsl:template name="ReturnClientInfo" match="/">
   <xsl:param name="CustomerNumber"/>
                       <xsl:for-each select="/XMLCOVER/Task/TaskData/Contract/ContractRoles/ContractRole[@ClientRoleType != ‘001’]/Customer/Identifiers/Identifier[@SocialNumber = $CustomerNumber]">
                       <xsl:if test="position()=1">
                                      <!—Print client details once -->                                             
                        </xsl:if>
                      </xsl:for-each>
                 </xsl:template>
```

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Please post a full (i.e. working) XSLT stylesheet and a sample of your XML input and the output you expect. Then I am sure your question can be answered.

Answer (score 2):

May be the mistake is in `ContractRole[@ClientRoleType != ‘001’]` it should be `ContractRole[ClientRoleType != ‘001’]` without @ symbol.
If it is not working provide me the xml structure.